# Can we display standard buttons in a custom lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

I have created a custom lightning component displayed as button "Convert" on the record page. I am looking to make the record page look consistent by displaying the standard buttons in the custom lightning component instead of the highlight panel.

Something like this:

[image: Standard buttons]

Can we achieve this in lightning?

Comment: Why not just implement force:lightningQuickAction and put your custom button with all the other standard buttons?

Comment: @sfdcfox I want to display a success toastmessage , and if I use Quickaction it pops up modal dialogbox. Inorder to avoid that I created a lightning component with button.

Comment: @sfdcfox - I believe this is why - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/173002/is-there-a-way-to-not-have-quickaction-modal-dialog-box - Looking forward to SF providing a way to do this

Comment: @Eric That makes more sense. Still, I don't think I can advocate trying to hack up the UI this way... they did say they'd give us an upgrade later...